# What time of day does the Google Apps email sending limit reset?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email

What time of the day does the Google App daily limit of 500 emails reset?

I'm planning on using two providers. If I hit the limit of 500 emails, I want to use the other provider.

But is this a rolling limit, or does the limit reset at 12 PST/EST etc.?

Comment: Just a suggestion: if you plan to send so many emails, then you should use an appropriate service. I'm a happy user of MailChimp if you need to send newsletters (instead of single-recipient messages), plus it's free to up to 500 recipients and 2500 messages/month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "within 24 hours". I've seen varying times. If you wait 24 hours you should be fine. You could create a mailing list in Google Groups to work around this.

See this help document for more info: [Sending Limits](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22839)